# How to optimize the apply function in pandas for calculating levenshtein distance?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am trying to find Levenshtein between 2 columns using the apply function but it is extremely slow.

```
from textdistance import levenshtein

temp['dist'] = temp.apply(lambda x: levenshtein.distance(x['address1'],x['address2']),axis=1)
```

It takes about 2 minutes for 733,000 rows and I have to perform this multiple times. Is there a way to optimize this using vectorization?

Comment: Have you tried converting them to numpy and calculate it instead?

Comment: Try to use python-Levenshtein package (written in C) first. If it's not sufficient, try to use multiprocessing module.